# divs scrolling down the page instead of in 2 rows

Tags: css, html, positioning

I'm sitting here scratching my head here, I should have 2 rows of 4 divs, as it shows in dreamweaver, though when it comes to uploading it they just go down the page one under the other.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, print, projection"  href="css/common.css"</link> 

<div id="mainimage"><?php include_once "projects/wc2/mainimage.php"; ?></div>
<div id="titletext"><?php include_once "projects/wc2/titletext.php"; ?></div>
<div id="images">
<div id="1" class="thumb">Hello I am a thumbnail!</div>
<div id="2" class="thumb">Hello I am a thumbnail!</div>
<div id="3" class="thumb">Hello I am a thumbnail!</div>
<div id="4" class="thumb">Hello I am a thumbnail!</div>
<div id="5" class="thumb">Hello I am a thumbnail!</div>
<div id="6" class="thumb">Hello I am a thumbnail!</div>
<div id="7" class="thumb">Hello I am a thumbnail!</div>
<div id="8" class="thumb">Hello I am a thumbnail!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#site {
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 960px;
}

/* ---------------------------------------- */
/* leftside - including logo and navigation */
/* ---------------------------------------- */

#leftside {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 600px;
    width: 325px;
    background-color: #FFF
}

#logo {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#nav {
    position: relative;
    font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 40px;
    left: 25%;
}

    /* link styling */

    a:link {color: #000; text-decoration: none;}   /* unvisited link */
    a:visited {color: #000; text-decoration: none;} /* visited link */
    a:hover {color: #F60; text-decoration: none;} /* mouse over link */
    a:active {color: #F60; text-decoration: none;}  /* selected link */



/* ------------------- */
/* content and gallery */
/* ------------------- */

#content {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 600px;
    width: 635px;
    background-color: #FFF
}

#mainimage {
    position: absolute;
    height: 420px;
    width: 400px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 97px;
}

.image {
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666; 
    -box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666;
}

#titletext {
    font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 420px;
    width: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 500px;    
}

/* ---------------------- */
/* thumbnails - 8 of them */
/* ---------------------- */

#images {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: 0px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 700px;
    top: 600px;
    left: 100px;
}

.thumb {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}

#1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 33px;
    left: 20px;
}

#2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 33px;
    left: 190px;
}

#3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 33px;
    left: 360px;
}

#4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 33px;
    left: 530px;
}

#5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 203px;
    left: 20px;
}

#6 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 203px;
    left: 190px;
}

#7 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 203px;
    left: 360px;
}

#8 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 203px;
    left: 530px;
}
```

Any light shed on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't you just love dreamweaver? Web design != Print design, what you see in the graphical editor isn't always what you get in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use `position: absolute` on the ID of each image? That doesn't seem like a very scalable solution.

Instead, because your thumbnails are of a fixed size, you may as well add `display: inline-block` to your `.thumb` style.

Here's the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/hCkBz/

Also, the reason the ID CSS styles aren't working is that an ID isn't allowed to start with a number. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name

Comment: Cheers Chris, getting rid of the absolute positioning and adding inline-block in sorted it, looks wrong in dreamweaver but correct in browser so I'm happy!

Comment: never trust WYSIWYG editors, always go straight to the source ;)

Comment: yea indeed! though having just numbers for my classes didn't cause any problem, but have changed them just incase.

Comment: Though I've just come up with another problem, doing it that way doesn't have the spacing round each box, wanted it 33px spacing on the coloums and 20px on the rows.

Comment: to `.thumb`, add `margin: 33px 20px 0 0;`

Comment: thats the one, couldn't think what it was, was adding padding to it! cheers for all ya help :)